# Android Read File Names SDCard

Tags: android, sd-card

I want to get file names stored in sd card android, but i could not find a proper solution.
Can somebody please help me??

```
public GetFileNames(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File dir = new File(sdCard, "path");
        String name;
        GenerateAlertBox alert = new GenerateAlertBox();
        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()){
                name = f.getName();
                // do whatever you want with filename
            alert.GenerateAlertBoxes(name, context);
            }
        }
    }
```

I found this,but I don't the the path.

Comment: The question has already been discussed a lot of times here on Stack Overflow... Whats your concrete problem? Any errors/exception/logcat output? Try to be more precise to help people helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all the files in the top folder of the SDCard you can do something like this:

```
public GetFileNames(Context context) {
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()){
            name = f.getName();
            fileNames.add(name);
        }
    }
    //Do whatever you want with fileNames array. 
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to get your apps private filenames you should do this:

```
public GetFileNames(Context context) {
    File dir = context.getFilesDir();

    ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()){
            name = f.getName();
            fileNames.add(name);
        }
    }
    //Do whatever you want with fileNames array. 
}
```

Comment: I am new in android, my files are stored if I check from DDMS, data/data/package name, can I list all files in there by this function @tasomaniac

Comment: That folder is not in the SDCard at all. Thats you apps private folder. I am updating the code to get that files.